# The files created by the open-function do not show in my dir

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I've got a problem with the open-function. At least I think it is the open-function. Somehow I cannot see the file that open("(...)", "w") creates in my directory but I can read from it. 
(Also yesterday the code worked fine)
Thats my code:

```
FILE_NAME = "new.txt"
with open(FILE_NAME, "w") as file_object:
    file_object.write("this is a new file")
```

Comment: Most likely, you are mistaken about your working directory. It is almost always best to use the full path to avoid this, otherwise, it will default to your *working* directory. You can programmatically check this by putting `import os` and then something like `print(os.getcwd())`

Answer (score 1):

Code looks fine. If you ran the code and can read the code from python, it means you created the file successfully, but you are running the python code in a working directory different from the directory you are looking at.

Try

```py
import os
os.getcwd()
```

to see where the file was written to.

Comment: First of all: Thank you for the os-module. Didn't know about that! 
I just moved the folder and can no longer read my .txt file. Seems like creating it didn't work. But is Python not creating the .txt file in the directory the Python file is in? So it should work if i create and read in the same code?

Comment: Now I can read it again... Didn't change my code tho. 
However still cannot see my created file

Comment: Because you passed "new.txt" to "open", it is a relative path as opposed to an absolute path. This means that the file will be created wherever you run your python code. You can run your python script outside of the directory where its created. Lets say your code is in a folder called "code", you can call `python3 code/myscript.py` and it will create the new text file outside of `code` and in wherever your current working directory is.

Comment: oh! Thank you! 
I ran my code with cmd prompt by moving into the directory in which my code is and then execute it. That should put my file into the correct directory right?

Comment: No the file still does not show in the directory. Also if i type the filename into cmd prompt, the file cannot be found. But I can read from it in my code